# Should I continue using Mootools now that MS is backing up JQuery?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I've been using Mootools for the last couple of months without knowing that MS was including JQuery with their new releases (like MVC). Now I'm not sure if I should switch to JQuery considering that I will be developing on MS tools and frameworks for the next years.
I would like to hear from more experienced developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to evaluate whether the framework fits your needs.  Knowing that MS has included jQuery may influence you towards that framework if it fits your needs.  If it won't work for you, though, it doesn't matter who endorses it.  That said, I have switched from Prototype/Scriptaculous to jQuery and I'm pretty happy with the change.

Note also that you can use jQuery in [noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict) mode (and "extreme" noConflict) if you find that you have a need for things from other frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I wouldn't switch to jQuery from Mootools if you paid me, but that's because I prefer Mootools' framework approach over jQuery's toolbox approach.  Your mileage may vary, of course; particularly if you just need a really fast way to get amazing transitions and Ajax up and running jQuery can be great.  A wonderful article comparing the two is here if you need a really thoughtful comparison:

http://jqueryvsmootools.com/

Answer (score 3):

Considering that Microsoft is also providing **free support** for jQuery as well, I think yeah, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old thread but have to remind ince more that MooTools and jQuery are quite different.

MooTools is modular and you can include only what you want. MooTools has evrything jQuery has in about 3/4 of its modules. You can load just that if you are looking for jQuery-alike library **or** you can remove just that and use jQuery for DOM and MooTools for other things.

Both can coexist. They are different.